# Presentation of sys.argv for conditional statement

Tags: python, args, sys

I have a function set up like:

```
args = sys.argv[1:]
if args:
    if args[0] in Constants.envs.keys():
        environment = Constants.envs[args[0]]
```

but I feel this isn't very clean looking.  Is there a better way to check for an argument and if valid, set a variable to it?

Comment: since python statements are lazy, you can combine your two `if` statements: `if args and len(args) > 0 and args[0] in Contants.env.keys():`

Comment: @Tyler: All that's really needed is `if args and args[0] in Contants:`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just combine the two `if` statements?

```
args = sys.argv[1:]
if args and args[0] in Constants.envs:
    environment = Constants.envs[args[0]]
```

You could also use the dict's `get` method, which returns a default value if the key is missing. This means you don't have to check `args[0] in Constants.envs.keys()`.

```
args = sys.argv[1:]
if args:
    environment = Constants.envs.get(args[0])  # will return None if the key is missing
```

Comment: Also you can pretty much remove `args` variable. So it will be as follows:
    
    `if sys.argv[1]:
        environment = Constants.envs.get(sys.argv[1], None)`

Comment: @Rob, you're right. The condition is incorrect. It should be `if len(sys.argv) > 1`